# Android Studio: Select Deployment target

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

When I click on run in the android studio. The select deployment target pops up with connected devices . I have my phone connected to it and there is about three emulators also connected.

P.S: Note that I have been running it before and it works. And I have searched for answers on google for two days straight and still not found any solution.

Comment: And what is the problem? Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: I agree this is unclear. To me, the problem is that it _appears_ to show up randomly when I run my app and not whenever I do want the window to appear.